# Conditional Copy of cell ranges between different files

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out how to implement the following algorithm in an Excel Macro.
I've got two excel files I would like to merge, let's call them fileA and fileB, and the macro is in fileB.
What I would like to do is the following:

```
    do{
if cells(N,j) of file A is not empy{ //where N is the column and j is the row
copy content of range (Nj:Pj) of fileA into fileB;
j++;
} while(fileA.Cells(H,j) is not empty
```

Is there anybody out there who can help me?
Thank you,
Dan

Comment: i'm still confused... looking at your code, you want to copy alls columns from your source which are empty in your target-sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have provided frame work mode for your requirement, Look into it

```
    Sub test1()

        Dim wb1 As Workbook
        Dim wb2 As Workbook

        Dim ws1 As Worksheet
        Dim ws2 As Worksheet
        Dim file1 As String
        Dim file2 As String
        Dim j, N  as Long

           j =1
           N =1           

        ' File Path
        file1 = "C\test1.xlsx"
        file2 = "C\test2.xlsx"


        ' File Opening
        Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=file1)
        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=file2)

        ' Assigning sheet
        Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("sheet1")
        Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("sheet1")

        ' use  Do and loop statement
        ' Cells( Row, Column Number)

        Do
            ' I have used length to check the if it is empty or not
            If Len(ws1.Cells(j, N).Value) > 0 Then

           ' Provide appropriate column number and row number
           ' For example A column, Column number is 1, B it is 2

    ' from copy range is ws1.Cells(Row1, col1)
    ' To copy range is ws1.Cells(Row2, col2)

           ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(Row1, col1), ws1.Cells(row2, col2)).Copy

           ws2.Paste ws2.Cells(Row3, col3)

           Application.CutCopyMode = False
           Application.CutCopyMode = True


            End If

            j = j + 1

       Loop Until Len((ws1.Cells(j, N).Value)) > 0


        End Sub
```

Comment: warning: your `Do ... Loop` doesn't has an exit-condition

Comment: How does it exit from the do while?

Comment: @DanCapo I have added the condition the below

Comment: @newjenn does Cells accept variables as input? the row index is actually j.

Comment: Yes cells can accept variable for example
Dim str1 as string 

str1 ="Hello"
ws1.cells(1,1).value = Str1

Comment: It's working great. How can we improve it to let me choose file1 from menu?

Comment: @DanCapo that is a different question and should get its own question.  Also you should accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: j= j +1 ' This  statement will increment the j value

Comment: when working with `option explicit` you need do declare j with `Dim j as Long`

Comment: @DirkReichel Thanks. VBA automatically assign  data type. If you use Option Explicit , you have to compulsorily initialize variable

Comment: the first use is in `If Len(ws1.Cells(j, N).Value) > 1 Then`... `j` may be declared as a `Variant` so it will be 'empty' and not `0`... however... even as `Long` it will encounter an error... `cells(x,y)` doesnt work with 0

Comment: @DirkReichel Yes, However, row number start with 1 , So j =1 in the beginning

Comment: yes. should be enough... i'd do it in a different way at all... however, having a workable solution doesn*t need a second solution

Comment: by the way, i'm still not able to copy the cells. files do open but they do not change.

Comment: What is value last value of j. Sheet names in workbook1 and workbook2

Comment: maybe reopening the file containing the macro is the issue? it is file2 actually

Comment: I have specified sheet1 as default, plz check the name of the sheet in the workbook

Comment: Okay. I am not sure about your question.

Comment: just a hint: check `ws2.Paste ws2.Cells(Row3, col3)` also the line `ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(Row1, col1), ws1.Cells(row2, col2)).Copy`

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. Below I've also posted the code i'm currently using, which i've slightly tuned.

Answer (score 0):

Just for having a workable solution try this:

```
'this will check the given upper cell for each row in your target
'if it is empty, it will copy the same range of your source to it
'it stops as soon as the given upper cell in your source is empty
Sub test()
  Dim wsCopy As Worksheet, wsPaste As Worksheet
  Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Long  'x = upper row / y = column / z = lower row
  Set wsCopy = Workbooks("FileA.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1") 'your source-workbook
  Set wsPaste = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' your target-workbook
  x = 1 'set the row to check here
  y = 1 'set the first column to check here
  z = 1 'set the lower row for the range to copy
  Do
    If IsEmpty(wsPaste.Cells(x, y)) Then
      wsPaste.Range(Cells(x, y), Cells(z, y)) = wsCopy.Range(Cells(x, y), Cells(z, y))
    End If
    y = y + 1
  Loop Until IsEmpty(wsCopy.Cells(x, y))
End Sub
```

or another one:

```
'note: this will copy entire columns
'it skips columns which are not empty in your target worksheet
'it stops at the first empty column in your source worksheet
Sub test()
  Dim wsCopy As Worksheet, wsPaste As Worksheet
  Dim y As Long  ' y = column
  Set wsCopy = Workbooks("FileA.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1") 'your source-workbook
  Set wsPaste = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' your target-workbook
  y = 1 'set the first column to check here
  Do
    If IsEmpty(wsPaste.Cells(Rows.Count, y).End(xlUp)) Then
      wsPaste.Column(y) = wsCopy.Column(y)
    End If
    y = y + 1
  Loop While IsEmpty(wsCopy.Cells(Rows.Count, y).End(xlUp))
End Sub
```

both won't copy any formating
however: if you want to also copy it then change:

```
'for the first change
wsPaste.Range(Cells(x, y), Cells(z, y)) = wsCopy.Range(Cells(x, y), Cells(z, y))
'to
wsCopy.Range(Cells(x, y), Cells(z, y)).Copy
wsPaste.Range(Cells(x, y), Cells(z, y)).Paste

'for the second change
wsPaste.Column(y) = wsCopy.Column(y)
'to
wsCopy.Column(y).Copy
wsPaste.Column(y).Paste
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you to everyone who helped me in solving this problem. 
I had to tune the proposed solution in order to let it work.
Please note that, since it opens both the source and the destination files, this macro has to be put into a third file.
Following the code:

```
Private Function get_user_specified_filepath(index As Integer) As String
        'This function is obtain the strings containing source and destination files, along with their path.
        Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
        Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
             fd.AllowMultiSelect = False
             If (index = 1) Then
             fd.Title = "Please select source file."
        Else
             fd.Title = "Please select destination file."
        End If
             If fd.Show = -1 Then
                 get_user_specified_filepath = fd.SelectedItems(1)
             Else
        End If
    End Function

    Sub test1()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim file1, sConflicts As String
    Dim file2 As String
    Dim j, H, N, Q As Long
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim conflicts As Long
    conflicts = 0
    index = 1
    j = 2
    ' These variables are helpers used to identify column index
    H = 8
    N = 14
    Q = 17
    R = 18
    S = 19
    V = 22

    ' File Opening
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(get_user_specified_filepath(index))
    'index is used to manage source/dst in the dialog output
    index = 2 
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(get_user_specified_filepath(index))

    ' Assigning sheet
    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Foglio2")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Foglio2")

    ' use  Do and loop statement
    ' Cells( Row, Column Number)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do

        If Not IsEmpty(ws1.Cells(j, N)) Then

       ' Provide appropriate column number and row number
       ' For example A column, Column number is 1, B it is 2

        ' from copy range is ws1.Cells(Row1, col1)
        ' To copy range is ws1.Cells(Row2, col2)

        ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(j, N), ws1.Cells(j, Q)).Copy
        'check for conflicts in the destination Range
        If IsEmpty(ws2.Cells(j, N)) Then
            'ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(j, N), ws2.Cells(j, Q)).PasteSpecial
            ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(j, N), ws2.Cells(j, Q)).PasteSpecial
            ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(j, N), ws2.Cells(j, Q)).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            Else
            'If conflicts are detected paste the cells on the right
            conflicts = conflicts + 1
            ws2.Paste ws2.Cells(j, S)
            ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(j, S), ws2.Cells(j, V)).Interior.ColorIndex = 7
        End If
        'Are these actually needed here?
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.CutCopyMode = True
        End If

        j = j + 1

    Loop Until Not Len(ws2.Cells(j, R).Value) > 0
    If (conflicts > 0) Then
        'After completion of the check, outputs the total number of conflicts detected
        sConflicts = "Please check for conflicts, total: " & conflicts
        MsgBox sConflicts
    End If
    wb1.Close
    wb2.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    End Sub
```